# Special needs for KVM switch

Tags: kvm

We have two computers to be connected to a KVM switch and from there to a touch screen. We want users to be able to switch between computers only by using touch screen.

So. Is there a KVM switch, where we could trigger a switch to another computer from an application?

There are switches, where you have to use hardware buttons in order to switch. These are not acceptable for us. Then there are switches where some keyboard combinations (e.g. Ctrl-F1, Ctrl-F2) allow to switch between computers.

We need the third kind of KVM switch, where the switching could be done from the application. The switches that do switching with the keyboard cannot be used for that purpose. The switch intercepts the keyboard combination to make a switch before that combination reaches the computer. If we would simulate keyboard events within the application, that would never get to the switch.

I expect it would be very difficult to find such piece of hardware. Just imagine you have two computers connected to such a switch both demanding an active connection because of malfunctioning application.

I am trying to find something like this with no luck. The problem is we have user requirements asking exactly for such a switch.

Do you have any idea if something like that is available anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: A touchscreen is usually treated as a special case of a mouse (or trackpad).  Have you tried looking for KVMs that can switch based on mouse input?

Comment: @Mark I have and found nothing. Well, in the meantime we have presuaded users that this will not work. It seems that we are going to implement a simpler solution. Anyway it would be nice to know if switches of that kind exist somewhere. I doubt, they do.

Comment: https://www.raritan.com/products/kvm-serial/kvm-over-ip-switches/enterprise-ip-kvm-switch - KX III SDK & API